# Does exist two numbers that multiplied (or divided) each other introduce error?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Here's the [bank](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a146a301cf94ff5) of tests I'm doing, learning how `FP` basic ops (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) would introduce errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(100);

    double a = 0.499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375;

    double original = 47.9;
    double target = original * a;    
    double back = target / a;

    std::cout <<  original << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  back << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  fabs(original - back) << std::endl; // its always 0.0 for the test I did
}
```

Can you show to me two values (`original` and `a`) that, once `*` (or `/`), due to `FP` math, introduce error?

And if they exist, is it possible to establish if that error is introduced by `*` or `/`? And how? (since you need both for coming back to the value; `80 bit`?)

With `+` is easy (just add `0.499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375` to `0.5`, and you get `1.0`, as for `0.5 + 0.5`).

But I'm not able to do the same with `*` or `/`.

Comment: `0.499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375 * 2`?

Comment: You mean like division by zero? Or what do you otherwise mean by "errors"?

Comment: @NathanOliver: nope, its 0 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4f1b2d8b9861ad9

Comment: Also note that if the system is using IEEE754 for floating point values, then for double precision there's only a little under 17 decimal places of precision, anything outside of that will lead to loss of precision.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I know. I just want to proof that, so multiply two value (and back to the original value) will introduce error (i.e. get a drift on `*` or `/`).

Comment: @markzzz So you really want two numbers, `a` and `b` where `a != (a * b) / b`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: uhm... not really. `0.5 + 0.499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375` should give to me the expected value `0.999999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375`. Instead, fp gives `1.0`. Is there any pairs of number that doesn't return the expected value using `*` (or `/`)?

Comment: Are you aware of how floating points work? You appear to be looking for operations that return non-perfect results, this will happen with most of them, especially with really big or really small numbers. Floating point operations don't guarantee mathematical correctness, they return approximate results.

Comment: @NathanOliver: anyway, here I have a `a != (a / b) * b` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f71d48fe7170117

Answer (score 0):

The output of:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    double a = 1000000000000.;
    double b = 1000000000000.;
    std::printf("a = %.99g.\n", a);
    std::printf("a = %.99g.\n", b);
    std::printf("a*b = %.99g.\n", a*b);
}
```

is:

```
a = 1000000000000.
a = 1000000000000.
a*b = 999999999999999983222784.
```

assuming IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point with correct rounding to nearest, ties to even.

Obviously, 999999999999999983222784 differs from the exact mathematical result of 1000000000000•1000000000000, 1000000000000000000000000.

Comment: Ok, so this is an example of a*b doesn't return expected result. First question: any example with low values and comma? i.e. "floating point"?

Comment: @markzzz: The presence of a comma doesn't make numbers floating point.

Comment: @rubenvb: of course! That's why I've written it between `""`. I meant values that once represented in decimal contains a comma.

Comment: @markzzz: Floating-point numbers scale. For binary floating-point numbers,  they can be multiplied or divided by two repeatedly without changing the relationships (up to the limits of the format’s range). So, to change 1000000000000 to a non-integer example, divide it by 2^13. Then we have 122070312.5•122070312.5 producing 14901161193847656, which is clearly not the exact mathematical result, since the exact mathematical result must end with “.25”.

Comment: @markzzz: It is not a “comma” that makes a number floating-point. Some people use a comma to mark the start of the digits that represent the fractional (sub-integer) part of a numeral, some people use a period. But the presence of non-zero sub-integer digits just means that a number is non-integer, not that it is floating-point. For a number to be floating-point, it must be represented with a point that floats. In other words, its representation must include multiplication by a base to the power of a variable exponent, such as M•2^e.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply any two large<sup>†</sup> numbers, and there is likely going to be error because representable values have great distances in the high range of values.

While this error can be great in absolute terms, it is still small in relation to the size of the number itself, so if you perform the reverse division, the error of the first operation is scaled down in the same ratio, and disappears completely. As such, this sequence of operations is stable.

If the result of the multiplication would be greater than the maximum value representable, then it would overflow to inifinity (may depend on configuration), in which case reverse division won't result in the original value, but remains as infinity.

Similarly, if you divide with a great number, you will potentially underflow the smallest representable value resulting in either zero or a subnormal value.

<sup>†</sup> Numbers do not necessarily have to be huge. It's just easier to perceive the issue when considering huge values. The problem applies to quite small values as well. For example:

```
2.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625 ×
2.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
```

Correct result:

```
4.410000000000000373034936274052605470949292688633679117285...
```

Example floating point result:

```
4.410000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625
```

Error:

```
2.30926389122032568296724439173008679117285652827862296732064351090230047702789306640625
× 10^-16
```

Comment: So this happens only for huge number? Not possible (for example) for numbers [-50.0, 50.0]? Why?

Comment: @markzzz simply because there are infinitely many rational numbers between every representable floating point numbers, and the gap between representable numbers widens as the exponent increases.

Comment: That's the "high level" motivation. The math one what is? When does it occurs the "round" up/down to another number? Can you show to me an example?

Comment: @markzzz the "rounding" happens in the floating point processor. There is simply no sequence of bits that represents the correct result, so best it can do is return the closest answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188893/discussion-between-markzzz-and-eerorika).

Answer (score 0):

> Does exist two numbers that multiplied (or divided) each other introduce error?

This is much easier to see with `"%a"`.

When the *precision* of the result is insufficient, rounding occurs.  Typically `double` has 53 bits of *binary* precision.  Multiplying 2 27-bit numbers below results in an exact 53-bit answer, but 2 28 bit ones cannot form a 55-bit significant answer.

Division is easy to demo, just try `1.0/n*n`.

```
int main(void) {
  double a = 1 + 1.0/pow(2,26);
  printf("%.15a,  %.17e\n", a, a);
  printf("%.15a,  %.17e\n", a*a, a*a);
  double b = 1 + 1.0/pow(2,27);
  printf("%.15a,  %.17e\n", b, b);
  printf("%.15a,  %.17e\n", b*b, b*b);

  for (int n = 47; n < 52; n += 2) {
    volatile double frac = 1.0/n;
    printf("%.15a,  %.17e %d\n", frac, frac, n);
    printf("%.15a,  %.17e\n", frac*n, frac*n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
//v-------v         27 significant bits.
0x1.000000400000000p+0,  1.00000001490116119e+00
//v-------------v   53 significant bits.
0x1.000000800000100p+0,  1.00000002980232261e+00
//v-------v         28 significant bits.
0x1.000000200000000p+0,  1.00000000745058060e+00
//v--------------v  not 55 significant bits.
0x1.000000400000000p+0,  1.00000001490116119e+00
//              ^^^ all zeros here, not the expected mathematical answer.

0x1.5c9882b93105700p-6,  2.12765957446808505e-02 47
0x1.000000000000000p+0,  1.00000000000000000e+00
0x1.4e5e0a72f053900p-6,  2.04081632653061208e-02 49
0x1.fffffffffffff00p-1,  9.99999999999999889e-01  <==== Not 1.0
0x1.414141414141400p-6,  1.96078431372549017e-02 51
0x1.000000000000000p+0,  1.00000000000000000e+00
```

Comment: so `a = (a / b) * b` is never guaranteed in fp, right? the same for `a = (a * b) / b`